# How to define function that returns another function?

Tags: functions, parameters

I'm new to Mathematica and I have an issue:

I'm trying to define a function that accepts as parameter another function with parameter X and then returns a function also with parameter X.

Input:

```
transform[x_[y_]] := {y, x[y]}

explicitFunction[x_] := Cos[π*x]/x

explicitFunction[ab]

parametric[x_] := transform[explicitFunction[x]]

parametric[ab]

expectedResult[x_] := {x, Cos[π*x]/x};

expectedResult[ab]
```

Output:

1. `Cos[ab π]/ab`
2. `transform[Cos[ab π]/ab]`
3. `{ab, Cos[ab π]/ab}`

Output no. 1: How a call to the explicit function which will also be a parameter looks like.

Output no. 2: How a call to the transform function with the explicit function as parameter looks like on my computer.

Output no. 3: What I actually want to achieve.

Obviously I can write `expectedResult[x_] := {x, explicitFunction[x]};` but that's not the point.
What I need is to be able to use a function expression/call with a function parameter and use the result later as if it's another function.

Comment: use `SetAttributes[transform, HoldFirst]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Trace` to see the source of the problem. Namely, `explicitFunction[ab]` is evaluated to `Cos[ab π]/ab` before `transform` is called; and, since `Cos[ab π]/ab` does not match the required argument pattern `transform` is returned unevaluated:

```
Trace @ parametric[ab] // Column
```

[image]

**A fix:** Give `transform` the attribute [`HoldFirst`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html) to prevent evaluation of its argument:

```
ClearAll[transform, explicitFunction, parametric, x, y]

SetAttributes[transform, HoldFirst]

transform[x_[y_]] := {y, x[y]}

explicitFunction[x_] := Cos[π*x]/x

parametric[x_] := transform[explicitFunction[x]] 

parametric[ab]
```

> ```
>  {ab, Cos[ab π]/ab}
> ```